# Unity GameObject rendering below GameObject lower in the hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject (TopSquare) that is rendered after `PlayButton` in the hierarchy, yet the `PlayButton` is showing on top. This goes against Unity's rule of objects added last are shown over objects added previously.

[image]

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Try removing the material (LiberationSans) from the TopSquare.

Comment: Removed, but it's still behind: https://i.imgur.com/TU8Edcs.png

Comment: I can see that your `order in layer = 1` for the playbutton, please check if it is same as the `Canvas` or other `gameobjects`.

Comment: My `PlayButton` doesn't have order in layer (as it doesn't have a Sprite renderer component), only my `TopSquare` has that.

Comment: Try adding a RectTransform component to it which will replace the default Transform.

Comment: That worked, but only when I changed the Z value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square is a sprite that is an object in the World, while the button exists in the UI layer over it.

You have to use UI Image for black square instead of sprite renderer (Right-click on parent -> UI -> Image)